# How to find how a hash in generated in an iOS app

Tags: ios, frida, hash-functions

I'm currently working on an iOS app to replicate a signature which looks to be generated with a MD5 hash. I'm currently using Frida, but haven't had any luck replicating it. [I've used the script to hook on to general crypto functions](https://github.com/noobpk/frida-ios-hook), but nothing MD5 related seems to go on here. I've also hooked onto the CC_MD5 function, but it isn't displaying me the correct hash, so I'm guessing the app is using another library. I've had success with Android, as I can 1) see the source code with Jadx 2) Easily hook onto the MD5 class.

Any tips on how I can approach this? It would be greatly appreciated!